# PDO subquery using variable within a loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, subquery

I am trying to write a query within a While loop using a dynamic variable but can't seem to get it working correctly. I am new to PDO so I'm not 100% if this is even the correct way to go about doing this.  The connection to the database ($db) works fine, and the query runs fine without the second $STH2 lines.  Please help :)

```
<?php

//This will list player info so the user can get the correct player  ID
$STH = $db->query('SELECT id, name, tag from wdlTeams');

//Setting the fetch mode
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//Create listbox object and populates options with team names 
echo "<select name='teamID'>";
while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $tag = $row['tag'];
    $seasonId = $row['seasonId'];

    $STH2 = $db->prepare('SELECT name from wdlSeasons where id=$seasonId');
    $STH2->execute();
    $seasonName = $STH2->fetchColumn();

    echo "<option value='$id'>$tag - $name ($seasonName)</option>";
    echo "<br />";
}
echo "</select>";

?>
```

I have also tried changing to

```
 $STH2 = $db->prepare("SELECT 'name' from 'wdlSeasons' where id='$seasonId'");
```

but with no luck

Comment: Prepared statements don't make sense at all when you, however, inject the variables into the SQL string directly. At least in MySql `'` isn't the correct quote for indentifiers, try backticks instead. Furthermore PHP doesn't interpolate in single qoutes.

Comment: Instead of the 2nd query in the loop, just do a joined query on the 1st query -> `SELECT wT.id, wT.name, wT.tag, wS.name as seasonName from wdlTeams wT LEFT JOIN wdlSeasons wS on wS.id=wT.seasonId`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$STH2 = $db->prepare('SELECT name from wdlSeasons where id=:id');
$STH2->bindParam(':id', $seasonId);
$STH2->execute();`